# Should you format your disk running Ubuntu?

Tags: format

Back in the days on Windows, I used to format my disk used with Windows once a year or so. Would you recommend the same for Ubuntu?

Comment: never felt like to format anything like for two years only if needed indeed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There never was a reason to format a disk in Windows unless for re-installing the OS or another OS. Defragmentation yes but that was inside Windows. Regarding the comment: people tended to format to get rid of malware in Windows but (to me) that is similar to blowing up the house to kill 1 mosquito. In general malware can be removed without a format but it was ofcourse the easiest method. We in general do not have malware (or it is installed deliberately by the user).

There is not really a need to format a disk on a regular base; when you re-install you can format but even then you can install the same OS without formatting. As long as you system does not go over 95% full there is also no reason to defrag the disk.  If you do reach 95% defragging is just a band-aid; you probably need a larger hard disk.

So no.

Comment: I agree 100% , but people would format to "clean" malware and such as well. This is unnecessary on Linux (Ubuntu) a well.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen oh good one.

Comment: The reason i always saw for reformatting windows was because of the registry. The more programs you install/uninstall the more the registry gets bigger and more messy and there is no good way to clean it.

Comment: True. But even there it is possible to fix without a format.

Comment: @Atari911 There are multiple ways to clean the Windows registry. I can't imagine anyone reformatting (using a shotgun) to clean the registry (to kill a fly, though it's fun for some). Never knew of anyone reformatting for that reason. At least, no experienced developers I've known were ever likely to admit to doing it.

Comment: Honestly, I cant think of any developers who would admit to using a registry cleaner. Those things are seriously worthless and are normally geared toward the average computer user. I've literally spent an hour or more cleaning (hitting F3) out registry keys related to a single program. It is quicker in most cases to simply reformat with a clean image.

Answer (score 12):

I have a slightly different opinion.

Firstly, **there were occasionally good reasons to reformat Windows**. It slowed down [if you installed things](https://thepcspy.com/read/what_really_slows_windows_down/) (including fonts). That wasn't fragmentation, it was just Windows being Windows. The registry on earlier versions could also get bogged down just through everyday use. And then there's malware.

And I think some of those reasons exist in Ubuntu:

- Switching desktop environment leaves you with tonnes of duplicate apps and so much old config in your user directory.
- Occasionally we break things and don't know how to fix them. Installing takes 20 minutes, learning how Upstart or the X stack work takes a couple of years.
- And sometimes release upgrades just aren't as good as a fresh install. You'll upgrade and everything looks just a bit wrong. This is usually linked to major desktop changes, or things like that.

So yeah, sometimes it's nicer to reset to the "factory default", and much easier than trying to undo years of abuse.

But how often you need to do this will vary hugely. I do horrible things to my computers and servers so I tend to end up doing a fresh install on each every new LTS. A normal user might never get themselves in such a pickle.

Comment: All of the "occasional good reasons to reformat Windows" (or Ubuntu) you give are actually reasons to reinstall, not to reformat the disc.

Comment: But by reformat, I mean —as I think does the questioner— delete everything and start again. Just reinstalling leaves the crud we're trying to escape right there.

Comment: IBus was totally broken when I upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04 and I had no choice but to do a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting recreates the partitions on the hard drive.

### When would you do this?

> Disk formatting is preparing a storage device for initial use. In some cases, the formatting operation may also create one or more new file systems. The first part is "low-level formatting". Partitioning is the second part of the process, making the data storage device visible to an operating system. The third part of the process "high-level formatting" refers to the process of generating a new file system.

[Source, Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_formatting)

As it says, it's typically for initial use - either the first time ever, or for a reinstallation. You might also do it if you've corrupted something, or have unwanted file (such as malware - which you probably won't get on Ubuntu).

This means there is no need to format yearly for Ubuntu - or any operating system. I can't think of any advantage to formatting yearly over leaving it - and reinstallation is a pain to me.